# When to use "assessment" and when "rating"

Tags: word-choice, difference

While proofreading a text I came across the sentence

> On the day of harvest the disease rating was conducted to determine the severity of the
> infection.

when translating it to german and back (which I often do to be sure that there are no grammatical mistakes) the translation website proposed this alternative:

> On the day of harvest, disease assessment was performed to determine the severity of infection.

Now in this case the assessment/rating refers to grading each disease on a scale of 0 to 4, so I presume rating is the correct word, but I'm not entirely sure and I don't know what this feeling is based on. Is there any general rule on when to use which word, assessment, grading or rating? Or even a different word?

Comment: "assessment" is more general, as you're "assessing" the severity of the infection by rating it. Either one would fit, but I'd say "assessment" sounds better here since you say you're "determining the severity" already. But either fits.

Comment: It'll depend mostly on how the jargon is used in that particular field. Both "assessment" and "rating" make sense, but probably only one is used in the normal day-to-day.